# How to set state color of button in android?

Tags: android, button

I want to custom button ,

If user pressed it will show red color and still show red until user pressed other button

how to do this?  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
      final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
  final Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

      });
      b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnClickListeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to change the background of the Button using [setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) or setBackgroundDrawable()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) for your button and set the background to a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that tests for the `android:state_checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button1.setOnClickListeners(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  }
});


button2.setOnClickListeners(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). A quick Google found this article: http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/ that explains them step by step. That way you don't need any code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that you need to save as an .xml file and place into your drawable folder.
The `android:drawable` tags point to the drawable resources for each button state. You can shorten this list if you want to.
Then you can use it as a drawable when creating your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_normal" />

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_normal" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_pressed" />

    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_normal" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_normal"/>
</selector>
```